# Header not getting written in csv at the time of export from python

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv

I am using python 3.4. I am exporting some results from python to a csv file. However my headers are not getting written. Given below is the piece of code I am using

with open('C:/Twitter_crawl/scoring_tweet.csv', 'r') as fp:

```
with open('scored_tweets.csv', 'w',newline='') as op:
    headers=['processed_tweet','sentiment']
    a = csv.DictWriter(op,delimiter=',',fieldnames=headers)
    for line in fp.readlines():
        sentiment = NBClassifier.classify(extract_features(getFeatureVector(line)))
        a.writerow({'processed_tweet':line,'sentiment':sentiment})
```

The file is created with data populated but no headers. Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

To write the header, you must call the csv.DictWriter.writeheader method: writerow just write rows...